# vb.net Is there a simple way to add a sound to a button click

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a simple way of doing this

I found this online and I am getting an error

```
 Declare Function apisndPlaySound Lib "winmm" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" _
(ByVal filename As String, ByVal snd_async As Long) As Long


Function PlaySound(ByVal sWavFile As String)
    ' Purpose: Plays a sound.
    ' Argument: the full path and file name.

    If apisndPlaySound(sWavFile, 1) = 0 Then
        MsgBox("The Sound Did Not Play!")
    End If
End Function
```

A call to PInvoke function 'WindowsApplication3!WindowsApplication3.Module1::apisndPlaySound' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: Hi hows it going, did our assistance help, is your problem fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SoundPlayer class, in VB.net you can access it with the My keyword as in:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(location)
```

But if its for a button click, you'll get a perf bottleneck (by maxing out IO) reading a *.wav file everytime a user clicks the button. In that case I recommend using:

```
Beep()
```

Also as a general rule of thumb, [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) by investigating/researching methods in the .Net framework first, before resorting to the Win32 API's. HTH

Comment: I don’t think a sort sound will offer a noticeable latency, and `Beep` is hardly a replacement.

Comment: @KonradRudolph your rep is outstanding! I have re-read your comment a couple of times. For the OP's interest here is a post to explain how I went off on (Perf bottleneck) tangent, if you do use a wav all I was trying to say was make sure the file is small: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469111/playing-a-wav-too-fast-messes-up/8483772#8483772 Thanks for picking me up on it Konrad.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a totally different signature for PlaySound in winnm.dll.
According to [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm/PlaySound.html) you should declare

```
<DllImport("winmm.dll")> _
Shared Function PlaySound( _
   ByVal szSound As String, _
   ByVal hModule As UIntPtr, _
   ByVal fdwSound As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

and call with:

```
 PlaySound(sWavFile, IntPtr.Zero, SoundFlags.SND_FILENAME Or SoundFlags.SND_ASYNC)
```

where

```
SoundFlags.SND_FILENAME = &H20000
SoundFlags.SND_ASYNC = &H1
```

Comment: `PlaySound` != `sndPlaySound`.

Answer (score 0):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the signature expects an (unsigned) `Integer`, not `Long`; same for the return value. The sample code you found was probably for VB6.

```
Declare Function apisndPlaySound Lib "winmm" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" _
    (ByVal filename As String, ByVal snd_async As UInteger) As Integer
```

… or you use the [`PlaySound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function found by Steve, since `sndPlaySound` only exists for backwards compatibility anyway. Better yet, use the built-in capabilities showcased by Jeremy.